# udp connection support without recfrom() system call in server

Tags: sockets, udp

I have to implement a server-client program using UDP connection setup.
In which Server UDP writes data packets to port XXXX continuously, and client at any moment just read data. 
note : there should be no handshaking i.e server will not be knowing the client address at any point in time.

I have implemented UDP server-client program.
server uses client address and broadcast the packets.i.e there is handshake well before broadcasting data to client. (but this was rejected, has server knew client address and handshaking was involved)

I am expecting how to make UDP server independent of the client address, just write data to port, then after some time client connect to port and read the data. there is no server intervention in reading the data

Comment: Sounds like the server needs to send either broadcast or multicast packets.  With broadcast (supported for IPv4 only) every computer on the LAN will automatically receive the packets; the client only has to bind to the port and start receiving.  With multicast (supported for IPv4 and IPv6), the packets will automatically be received by any client on the LAN that joins itself to the same multicast address that the server is sending to.

Comment: Thank you very much @JeremyFriesner. If you have any good reference for the same, can you please share ??

Comment: @SachinSShetty I'm failing to understand the problem, I think you need to explain it differently.  could you also append a minimum working example to your question and explain why it's "rejected" using different/more standard terminology

Comment: @SamMason: Requirement was to broadcast message packets to client using UDP Connection.I had implemented as below                                                                                                 1) Server wait on clients                                                                                                                   2) client connect to sever (handshaking i.e. i will know the client address from recvfrom() systemcall), server then broadcast the message packets to clients.

Comment: 3) overtime, client can disconnect and server stop sending message packet to client. the above is applicable to multiple clients.                                                          After delivering the above feature to my client, client has informed that there will be no connect/disconnect request from client to server. my question is is it possible to broadcast log to clients using UDP setup without any handshaking with the server ??

Comment: as @JeremyFriesner said, if they're on the same LAN, then broadcast packets will make it through, otherwise, multicasting might work but the clients would need to join the group, which is effectively "handshaking".  general problem remains, how does the network/server know where to send the data such that the relevant clients get the data?

Comment: I wouldn't call joining a multicast group "handshaking", since the server program isn't involved in that transaction (i.e. the multicast join is a transaction only between the client program, its host OS, and in some cases the network switch)